# I'm having issues with pytest fixtures because of code duplication

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, code-duplication

I'm quite new to pytest and I've been told that fixtures help with code deduplication.
While generally true, I've come to an impasse where I don't really know on how to proceed, or what I've read was too confusing for me.

## Background:

I have a suite of tests that have different test data files. For each test, I'd like to load those test data files and run through the test cases. I don't want to load the test data file in each test file though, I would like to use a fixture instead.

#### This is what I have:

```
def load_test_data(path):
"""
:param path: The full path of the file containing the test data
:return: test data
"""
data = yaml.safe_load((open(path, 'r')))
return data


@fixture(params=load_test_data(PROJECT_JSON_TEST_DATA))
def get_test_data_project_json(request):
    data = request.param
    return data

@fixture(params=load_test_data(DATA_FOLDER_STRUCTURE_TEST_DATA))
def get_test_data_folder(request):
    data = request.param
    return data
```

This goes on for several fixtures, for each class of tests I'm doing. I would like to have a single 'test_data' loading, and based on the class I'm running the tests in to load the correct one. How do I get there?

The below code is in conftest.py

#### I've tried something like this:

```
@fixture(params=[load_test_data(NUSPEC_TEST_DATA),
                 load_test_data(PROJECT_JSON_TEST_DATA),
                 load_test_data(USER_GUIDE_TEST_DATA),
                 load_test_data(DATA_FOLDER_STRUCTURE_TEST_DATA)])
def get_test_data(request):
    data = request.param
    return data
```

But then, for each test, it tries to generate 4 different runs, based on the test data. My brain is all foggy and can't find the obvious solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using parametrize for this use case.

test.py

```py
import pytest
import yaml

filenames: list = ["NUSPEC_TEST_DATA", "PROJECT_JSON_TEST_DATA", "USER_GUIDE_TEST_DATA", "DATA_FOLDER_STRUCTURE_TEST_DATA"]


def load_test_data(path):
    """
    :param path: The full path of the file containing the test data
    :return: test data
    """
    data = yaml.safe_load((open(path, 'r')))
    return data


# parametrize will run through each item of the filenames list and run a test for each of those items. 
# Allowing you the ability to have individual test for each filename without having to write multiple duplicated test 
@pytest.mark.parametrize("file_name", [*filenames])
def test_data(file_name):
    data = load_test_data(path=file_name)
    return data
```

With parametrize you are able to build individual test that will loop through the given param, without having to write duplicated code.

See the below link for more information:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html

Comment: I think I didn't make my OP clear enough. That test_data is in conftest.py, and is a fixture to be used by other tests. The purpose of it is that it should load test data configurations for each test, and that I shouldn't make a different loading for each test. 

If this is what your code does, I will re-read the documentation again tomorrow and come back. Thank you either way!

Comment: So you want to load your data one time and then use throughout your test file?

Comment: I will have a test called test_project_json for instance. When I load testing data for it from a yaml file, I want the same fixture I use for test_project_json to be able to load for a different test, its specific testing data file. Say for another test called test_project_folder. 

As you can see the fixtures are identical for get_test_data_x, the only difference is the parameter.